# Make WebStorm to understand which vue components are registered globally

Tags: vue.js, webstorm

If I have some of my vue components registered globally, how can I make WebStorm to understand it and help me with autocomplete? I have some custom ui components registered globally from main js file like this:

```
  const requireComponent = require.context(
    './components',
    true,
    /^\.\/ui-kit\/global\/.*ui-.*\.vue$/
  )

  requireComponent.keys().forEach(function(fileName) {
    let baseComponentConfig = requireComponent(fileName)
    baseComponentConfig = baseComponentConfig.default || baseComponentConfig

    let baseComponentName =
      baseComponentConfig.name ||
      fileName.replace(/^.+\//, '').replace(/\.\w+$/, '')

    Vue.component(baseComponentName, baseComponentConfig)
  })
```

So I want to use such components without any imports. And I can, but the only issue here I haven't any recognition of such components from WS.

[image: No auto-completion screenshot]

WebStorm also marks this tag as

> Unknown html tag ui-input
>
> This inspection highlights unknown HTML tags, and lets mark such tags as Custom to avoid highlighting them as unknown in future

Sure if I've imported that component manually, suggestions from WebStorm work fine.

Comment: Found this link: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31682 in that question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51603017/semantic-ui-vue-components-not-recognized-by-webstorm --- so I think this question could be closed...

Comment: I don't think it's possible to make the IDE recognize components registered dynamically. Resolving them would require executing the code. So it's not likely that it will be ever fixed

Answer (score 1):

For those coming here, this is the solution:

1. Install [vue-docgen-web-types](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-docgen-web-types) in your project ([docs](https://github.com/JetBrains/web-types)): `npm i vue-docgen-web-types`
2. Add the following to `package.json`

```
    "scripts": {
        "update-web-types": "vue-docgen-web-types"
    },
    "web-types": "./web-types.json",
```

3. Run the `update-web-types` npm command.

If you also want to be able to click on your custom components to navigate to the source file, then you have to do the following since there is currently a pathing bug:

This is what you currently get in the generated `web-types.json` file:

```
          "source": {
            "module": "./src\\components\\General\\Page.vue",
            "symbol": "default"
          }
```

But if you fix the pathing to:

```
          "source": {
            "module": "./src/components/General/Page.vue",
            "symbol": "default"
          }
```

The everything works!

So just replace all "`//`" with "`\`" after you run the `update-web-types` npm command.

Jetbrains issues:

- [Vue + TypeScript: globally registered components not recognized](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-42655)
- [Vue: improve detection of the global components](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-31682)